# CSS don't work in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to create my own them in WordPress. I added index.php and style.css in root folder. I am trying change backgound color but nothing happened.

index.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
        <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
        <?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
    /* Theme Name: Test */

body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

It is working when I change CSS style in 'site customizer/CSS' tab, or when i add css style directly in html body tag.

What is wrong?

Comment: For sure background color should be like: `background-color: red`.

Comment: are you sure it's not client side problem? try refreshing without caching using CTRL+F5 or CTRL+SHIFT+R.

Comment: Use `background-color: #hex;` instead of `color:`. Also make sure that your css file is loaded and your rule is not overwritten by another.

Comment: Themes go in the wp-content folder, not the root

Comment: @ItayGanor CTR+SHIFT+R - it's help! Thank you very much!

Comment: @plesniak you welcome. should I add this to the answers? Is it the final one?

Comment: @j08691 Of course I placed files in wp-conten not in root folder. I misspoke. My mistake:)

Comment: @ItayGanor It's work so in my opinion you can add this to the answers. Can you write somthing more about this? Is it possible to avoid pushing this key combination after each style change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS files are being cached in your device for performance reasons. In order to refresh them, you have to refresh without caching, which is by `CTRL+SHIFT+R` or `SHIFT+F5`.

In order to avoid pushing this key combination after each style change, open your developer console (`CTRL+SHIFT+I`) and go to its settings (`F1`). Then enable **Disable cache (while DevTools is open)**. By doing that, as long as the developer console is opened, your refreshes won't use any cache.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if u want to change bg color use this..

```
body{
   background-color:red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `color` property is for the color of the text:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color

Use `background-color` instead.

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You are right! I made edit of my post. Thank you. I made mistake during write this post. On my page is `backround-color` instead `color`.